# How to replace a character in excel in special circumstances

Tags: excel, replace

So I have a 71563 x 3 dataset, which contains a list of chemical molecular formulas. An example of such a chemical formula is C40H56O4, where the letters represent a chemical and the number the multiplicity of them. What I want to do is replace all characters with the letter 'O' with a smaller case 'o', but only if that 'O' is between two numbers, and not if there is a character before it. So for example:-

C57H85N**9O9** would become C57H85N**9o9**, but C6H13**NO2** would remain the same. How would I go about writing out a formula for this in excel, if possible?

Thanks

Apologies I should of stated earlier that there are instances in which there is a number before the letter 'O', but it doesn't have anything after it. So for example:- C8H16O, which should be C8H16o

Comment: How about an **O** as the leading or trailing character??

Comment: It wouldn't work because I need it to only be replaced if there is an integer before it and not a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so my solution probably isn't the most compact however it does work using formulas. You will have to adjust to for the three columns however here is how it will work if all of your data was in column A alone.

1. Add this formula to column B. This ignores leading O's by starting at the second letter in the cell. It returns the position of the first O in the cell.

   `=FIND("O",A1,2)`
2. In column B add this which will give you the three letter string.

   `=MID(A1,B1 - 1,3)`
3. In column C put this which gives the first number.

   `=LEFT(C1,1)`
4. Column D checks if column C is an integer.

   `=IF(IFERROR(INT(D1),FALSE),A1,FALSE)`
5. Column E does the replacing.

   `=IF(E1 <>FALSE,REPLACE(A1,B1-1,3,LEFT(C1,1) & "o" & RIGHT(C1,1)),A1)`

Note that this assumes there will only be one O per molecule. I will attempt to update this to check for multiple O's.

EDIT:

I have it down to one a one cell formula. Keeping the above though to explain the steps.

```
=IF(IFERROR(INT(MID(A1,FIND("O",A1,2) - 1, 1)), FALSE) <> FALSE, REPLACE(A1,FIND("O",A1,2),1,"o"),A1)
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I'll quickly just give this a go too and see how it fairs but thank you!

Comment: This one does not solve the problem of the terminal "O."

Comment: Yes it does... Just tested my one line formula with the text `C40H56O` and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following **UDF** in a standard module:

```
Public Function xlate(s As String) As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, CH As String
    N = Len(s)
    xlate = ""
    If N < 3 Then
        xlate = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 2 To N - 1
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH <> "O" Then
            xlate = xlate & CH
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i - 1, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(s, i + 1, 1)) Then
                xlate = xlate & "o"
            Else
                xlate = xlate & "O"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    xlate = Left(s, 1) & xlate & Right(s, 1)
End Function
```

Then with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=xlate(A1)
```

and copy down

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=xlate(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1**

Here is the updated code to handle the terminal **O**

```
Public Function xlate(s As String) As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, CH As String
    N = Len(s)
    xlate = ""
    If N < 3 Then
        xlate = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 2 To N - 1
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH <> "O" Then
            xlate = xlate & CH
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i - 1, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(s, i + 1, 1)) Then
                xlate = xlate & "o"
            Else
                xlate = xlate & "O"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    xlate = Left(s, 1) & xlate
    If Right(s, 1) = "O" And IsNumeric(Right(xlate, 1)) Then
        xlate = xlate & "o"
    Else
        xlate = xlate & Right(s, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You sir are a wizard. Sorry I just realised that there are instances in which there is a number before the O, but no character or number afterwards, such as the case of C8H16O. How would I go about tweaking the code so it takes this into consideration as well?

Also going to learn more about macros from now on haha

Comment: How should this terminal **O** be handled??

Comment: So it should also become a lower case O, so C8H16O should be C8H16o unless there's a character before it

Answer (score 1):

## Formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(INT(MID(A1,FIND("O",A1)-1,1))),A1,IF(FIND("O",A1)=LEN(A1),A1,REPLACE(A1,FIND("O",A1),1,"o")))`

Comment: Upvoted for being cleaner than my formula. Never thought to use `ISERROR`.

Comment: They all seem to work great, sorry I can't accept all the answers but they're all brilliant! Thank you

Comment: My answer is the only one so far that solves the terminal "O" problem.

Comment: The one BradyK gave seems to have worked for the terminal "O" on my dataset

Comment: just checked through my dataset and all the terminal "O"s have been converted to O, but thank you as well for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: @jbarker2160 is my formula not replacing terminal O's for you? It does on my sheet.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a job for a VBA macro:

```
dim rng as range, subrange as range
rng = range("A1", "ZZ256")
for each subrange in rng
    rng.value2 = replace(rng.value2, "9O9", "9o9")
next rng
```

Comment: I agree with using a macro however you've only replace _9O9_ whereas the user wants any the solution in a where where (if _n_ is any number) there exists _nOn_ that the string becomes _n**o**n_